# Replace value in array based on other array

Tags: php

I would like to replace the value of a multidimensional array if a corrosponding array contains a certain value.

Basically, I have two multidimensional arrays. One contains the actual data and the other contains a yes/no for whether the first array should be modified.

Is there any way to do this:

```
if optB[i][i] contains 'yes'
        then opt[i][i] = '<strong>'.opt[i][i].'</strong>';
```

I'm lost as to whether this is even possible. Any help would be greatly appreciated -- thank you!

Thank you for the help so far. Here is the array:

```
[opt] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => value1
                [1] => value2
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => value3
                [1] => value4
            )

    )

[optB] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => on
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [1] => on
            )

    )
```

Comment: Could you post some sample arrays?

Comment: Yes, it's possible: loop over the array, compare with the other one and modify as needed.

Comment: Post the `print_r` return os the both arrays, it will make things easier to us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are some interesting arrays because usually numeric arrays always have a 0. I imagine you may have some different key combination so I think this is the best "future-proof" method:

```
foreach ($optB as $i => $optB2) {
    foreach ($optB2 as $j => $val) {
        if ($val) {
            $opt[$i][$j] = '<strong>' . $opt[$i][$j] . '</strong>';
        }     
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible.  You can do this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count(opt); $i++) {
    if ($optB[$i][$i] == "yes")
        opt[$i][$i] = '<strong>'.opt[$i][$i].'</strong>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be written like this:

```
if (strpos($optB[$i][$i], 'yes'))
    $opt[$i][$i] = '<strong>'.$opt[$i][$i].'</strong>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines:

```
foreach ($opt as $i => &$arr) {
    foreach ($arr as $j => &$val) {
        if ($optB[$i][$j]) {
            $val = "<strong>$val</strong>";
        }
    }
}
```

Modify as needed.